# Как правильней сделать проверку на ненулевые поля?

Tags: php

есть search.php которая обращается к API и получает из него в переменную $responce экземпляр класса stdClass с полями: title, type, year, genres ...

В последствии этими полями заполняются карточки на фронте. Но может быть ситуация, когда от API какое-то поле пришло пустым, в таком случае я хотел бы просто удалить это поле из конечного массива, который передается на фронт. Собственно и не пойму как сделать это правильно, можно конечно сделать проверку полей через switch, но может есть более красивое решение?

```
public function collectMovies(array $arr){
        foreach ($arr as $id){
           $responce = $this->responseToAPI('Title', $id);
           $this->moviesArr[] = array(
                'title'=>$responce->fullTitle,
                'type'=>$responce->type,
                'year'=>$responce->year,
                'genres'=>$responce->genres,
                'releaseDate'=>$responce->releaseDate,
                'image'=>$responce->image,
                'plot'=>$responce->plot,
                'directors'=>$responce->directors,
                'writers'=>$responce->writers,
                'stars'=>$responce->stars,
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: перебери в цикле $responce, если есть значение добавь в moviesArr

Comment: array_filter() если я правильно понял вопрос